# How to prove that any genus 2 curve is hyperelliptic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

How can one prove that any genus $2$ smooth curve is hyperelliptic? Remember that a smooth curve $C$ is called hyperelliptic if there exists a morphism $\phi:C \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $2$.

Comment: Hint: Consider the map by the linear system $|K_C|$.

Comment: $|K_X|=\mathbb{P}^1$ and the canonical map gives the double cover.  I made a mistake in my old computation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The hint given by Matt is true. But there are many nontrivial steps to prove your statement. Here is one proof:

Let $K_C$ be a canonical divisor of $C$. Thus, we have that $\mathcal{L}(K_C)\simeq\omega_C$. We know that the canonical sheaf $\omega_{C'}$ on a curve $C'$ of genus $g_{C'}\geq 2$ is generated by global sections. (Still, this is not trivial. The key points for this fact will be at the end of the proof.)

By Lemma II.7.8 of Hartshorne:=[H], we therefore get that $|K_C|$ is base point free since $g_C=2$. Also, $\dim|K_C|=g_C-1=1.$ Hence we have a morphism $\phi: C\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $\mathcal{L}(K_C)\simeq \phi^*(\mathcal{O}(1))$; cf. Remark II.7.8.1 of [H].

Lastly, we have to prove that $\deg(\phi)=2$. By Proposition II.6.9 of [H], we have that $$\deg(\phi)=\deg(\phi)\deg(P)=\deg(\phi^*(P))=\deg(K_C)=2g_C-2=2,$$ where $P\in\mathbb{P^1}.$ Here, $\deg(K_C)$ follows from the Riemann-Roch Theorem. We also used that $\mathcal{O}(1)\simeq\mathcal{L}(P).$ As a conclusion, we have proved that $deg(\phi)=2.$

Addendum for the nontrivial fact:
To prove that $|D|$ is base point free for a divisor $D$ on a curve $C$, it is enough to show that $\ell(D-P)<\ell(D),$ for all closed points $P\in C.$ Hence, our fact can be done by applying Riemann-Roch Theorem to $K_C-P,$ for all closed points $P.$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1716017)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A few comments: this problem is more than nine years old, and was asked by a user who has not been active on the site in more than eight years. It is unlikely that they will respond to you, so including a phrase like "let me know if you need help with this" might not be the best tactic. Further, leaving off the interesting part (the calculation that shows $|K_C|$ is base-point free) is perhaps questionable, especially since this is proven later in Hartshorne (lemma IV.5.1). Finally, `\dim` and `\deg` produce $\dim$ and $\deg$, which will make your text more visually appealing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have added the key points of the fact which I used in the proof.